# PHP query not updating in db throught form

Tags: php, html, mysql

i'm working on a project that includes a minimail/chat function that has the option to tick off when u have read the message and flag a user.

The flag and tick off options doesnt work anymore after i eddited something but i cannot find the problem anymore.

The game doesnt support newer versions of PHP for now.

- $m['id']; = 22
- $m['read'] = 0

**Query 1 =**
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["mark_read_x"]=> string(2) "10" ["mark_read_y"]=> string(2) "10" }

**Query 2 =**
array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["flag_user_x"]=> string(1) "8" ["flag_user_y"]=> string(1) "4" }

```
<?php
   $mid = $m['id'];

   if(isset($_POST['mark_read'])){
    $mid2 = $_POST['id'];
    $query2 = "UPDATE `user_messages` SET `read` = '1' WHERE `read` = '0' AND `user_messages`.`id` = '$mid2'";
    mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
    header("Refresh:0");
    }
?>

<?php if($m['read'] === '0'){ ?>

<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $mid; ?>">
   <input src="tick.png" title="Mark as read" type="image" alt="submit" name="mark_read">
</form>

<?php } else { echo ''; } ?>

<?php
   if(isset($_POST['flag_user'])){
    $mid2 = $_POST['id'];
    $query3 = "UPDATE `user_messages` SET `flagged` = '1' WHERE `flagged` = '0' AND `user_messages`.`id` = '$mid2'";
    mysql_query($query3) or die(mysql_error());
    header("Refresh:0");
   }
?>

<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $mid; ?>">
   <input src="exclamation.png" title="Flag message" type="image" alt="submit" name="flag_user">
</form>
```

Comment: What about it isn't working?

Comment: **obligatory warning** mysql_* functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Switch your code to use [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](//stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](//stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) Use [prepared parameterized statements](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: @aynber It doesnt update anything in the table from this code but when i inset it as sql into the table it works correctly..

Comment: You need to do some basic troubleshooting, then. `var_dump($_POST)`, and check for mysql_errors

Comment: @aynber
**first query =** array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["mark_read_x"]=> string(2) "10" ["mark_read_y"]=> string(2) "10" }

**second query =** array(3) { ["id"]=> string(2) "28" ["flag_user_x"]=> string(1) "8" ["flag_user_y"]=> string(1) "4" }

Comment: "The flag and tick off options doesnt work anymore after i eddited something but i cannot find the problem anymore"  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control

Comment: Also, some IDEs, such as [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) will keep a copy every time you save & then you can "compare with ... loacl history"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Changed

```
<input src="tick.png" title="Mark as read" type="image" alt="submit" name="mark_read">
```

to

```
<button type="submit" name="mark_read" style="padding: 0; border: none;"><img title="Mark as read" src="tick.png" /></button>
```

Input type failed to submit data because of the image type. works fine now.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you had a JS function handling the form submit. I was wondering what the heck those inputs you used were...

Answer (score 1):

This is obvious that you should always use `action =""` attribute whenever you use form tag even if you perform action on same page. You should  mention `action=""` or`action="#"` always in form tag and use `mysqli_*` function as it is improved version.